# Cannot ping Google Public DNS on 8.8.8.8

Tags: windows-7, ping, google-public-dns

I have a weird problem on my Windows 7 (x64) computer. I seem to cannot ping the Google Public DNS on one of its addresses (while the other works fine). The peculiar thing is that it fails with the `General failure.` error message which usually means that there is a problem with a network adapter/base connectivity and not a timeout as one would expect.

[image: Using ping on Windows 7]

I checked my routing tables for any anomalies and I even flushed them but the problem seems unrelated. All the other hosts I tried ping fine (either respond or timeout).

If I try to `tracert` or connect to the address via browser (yes, I know that it doesn't listen on port 80), it also fails instantaneously.

The reason I need to ping 8.8.8.8 is that I commonly use it as a test of Internet conectivity due to it being rememberable. The problem occurs no matter where I connect to the Internet (it is a laptop computer). What could be the cause of this anomaly?

*Note: I use native IPv6 connectivity.*

Comment: Assuming you've already tried a reboot...  Does it work in Safe Mode with Networking? Do you have any anti-virus or "Internet security" software running?

Comment: No, I don't use any Internet security solutions and the problem does persist after rebooting (even in Safe Mode w/ Networking)

Comment: Router's route tables perhaps?

Comment: Even if router's routing tables would be a problem, the ping would just timeout and not fail with General failure.

Comment: Yeah.. it seems more like the response is corrupted or something..  Tried updating network drivers?  Did this EVER work on this computer? :)

Comment: tracert? see if it's a particular point along the chain it's failing, or directly on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can rule out your computer and your network if you ping this address "from the internet" using a service like DNS Tools: http://dnstools.com/?count=1&portNum=80&ping=on&target=8.8.8.8&submit=Go! On this site it also does not work. However it works from my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by anti-virus and/or firewall software (e.g. McAfee, Kaspersky, Comodo).

If you only have the Windows 7 Firewall, try  Network and Sharing -> Windows Firewall -> Restore Defaults

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this question already? [Why do I get "General Failure" when pinging host name on a Win 7 node on the network?](https://superuser.com/questions/433416/why-do-i-get-general-failure-when-pinging-host-name-on-a-win-7-node-on-the-net)

It suggests several solutions and points to a microsoft kb article.