# Windows 7 - Can't get response from local servers after restart - Always timeouts

Tags: windows-7, port, xampp, windows-firewall

After a long uptime and the installation of some Windows Updates no local server is working. My development system is a Windows 7 x64 Professional installation. I had a full working XAMPP set-up before. The included servers don't answer any more. Neither Apache nor MySQL. I tried also Nginx and a small self-written Java-Listener to open a local port. They aren't working, too. So I tried to ping to my PC from local network, but got no answer. The PC is definitively connected to the same network, ping in the other direction is working. Ping from the PC itself to 127.0.0.1 causes a "Generic failure". (The same for ::1, localhost ...)

So what I have tried:

- Scanned for Malware
- Removed "Malwarebytes Anti Malware"
- Restarting of the whole system and servers (multiple times...)
- Tried to listen on 8080 - no answer
- Reinstalled XAMPP in other paths and started from there
- Started Apache and MySQL as process and as service (not at the same time!)
- Checked .../drivers/etc/hosts file
- Checked Apache's log files (no errors, only pid is logged)
- Set Apache's logging level to 'debug'
- Removed VMware, because this brought some new interfaces and was unused
- Disabled all interfaces without the one which connects my PC to the internet
- Checked all used ports and listening processes (with netstat)
- Checked ipconfig
- Checked all running processes and services (With taskmgr/ProcessExplorer)
- Checked IPv4 routing table and compared with a clean windows installation
- Checked connection with Chrome, Firefox, HeidiSQL, PuTTy and curl
- Checked Windows event logs, nothing really special there
- Windows Firewall

  - Enabled logging for dropped packages (all incoming packages will be dropped)
  - Switch off (no new logging output, but still connection timeouts, tried from control panel and manually from command line)
  - Switch on again (doesn't help)
  - Added rules for ports 80, 443, 3306, ... (doesn't help)
  - Checked that ingoing connections aren't generally blocked
  - Restarted Windows Firewall service manually

Web browsing, Email and Instant Messaging is still working without restrictions.
Has anybody any idea what can cause this behavior, what can I do against it, or which things I can test to get further information about the problem?

---

**Edit (same as in comment in first answer below):**

After [@user970638](https://superuser.com/users/162524/user970638) points me to digg further into the ping-problem, I tried the following steps:

1. Disabled IPv6 in my NIC configuration.
2. Installed Microsoft FixIt 50410 to prefer IPv4 before IPv6 because I saw when executing ping that localhost was resolved to ::1. ([as seen here](https://superuser.com/a/435871/163476))
3. Executed "netsh winsock reset" and reboot.

After these steps, Apache and MySQL server were working again. But only for some hours. I didn't reboot again in this time or did any changes to the network configuration. It just stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

"Ping from the PC itself to 127.0.0.1 causes a generic error"

That should tell you something right there. Try resetting your TCP/IP stack from an elevated command prompt:

**netsh int ip reset**

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This command alone didn't help. So I tried also the following:

1. Installed Microsoft FixIt 54010 to prefer IPv4 before IPv6 because ping resolved localhost to ::1.
2. Executed "netsh winsock reset" and reboot.

After these steps, Apache and MySQL server were working again. But only for some hours. I didn't reboot again in this time or did any changes to the network configuration. It just stopped working.

Comment: Damn! I'm inclined to suspect your physical network card or the driver itself. Reinstall the driver and/or swap network cards to further narrow the problem. Going through the event logs under the management console and tracking down any errors specific to the tcp/ip stack may prove informative as well.

Comment: I tried already both: reinstalling driver and swapping network cards. The event log was one of the first things I looked at. But there was nothing suspicious without a bluetooth driver which is failing. I removed the stick and deactivated the adapter.