# Why can I only ping if my command prompt is running as Administrator?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ping

I have a problem where, if I open a command prompt and try to ping a server, it gives me the following error:

> PING: transmit failed. General failure.

However, if I run the command prompt as Administrator, then I can ping the server.

I know there's a possibility that the registry permissions were changed incorrectly, but I don't know where something like ping would need to be reading in the registry.

Comment: A related question was discussed here: http://superuser.com/questions/433416/why-do-i-get-general-failure-when-pinging-host-name-on-a-win-7-node-on-the-net

Comment: Do you have any firewall/internet security software installed? Might be the creation of raw sockets for ICMP from a non-admin level account that are being blocked. Also check to make sure NLB is not enabled on the NIC. Can you also clarify if this is an IPv4 or IPv6 address that you are pinging?

Comment: I did see that other question, and I have IPv6 disabled.  Also, this is all IPv4 network.  You're right that it could be raw sockets, but I'm not doing anything like that.  Just a regular ping, and that works fine on another computer without running the command prompt as an administrator.  I turned off the firewall.

Comment: Ultimately I had to roll the system back to a system restore point from about a week ago, and then everything worked fine.  Not sure why I got the down-vote though...